# Extending idea of prime ideal to $(pq) = $ product of two prime ideals.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, ideals, integers

If $p,q$ are two primes then $xy \in (pq) \implies$

$$
x \in (p) \text{ or } y \in (p) \text{ and } \\
x \in (q) \text{ or } y \in (q) 
$$

by definition of prime ideal.   That means $xy \in (pq) \implies x \in (pq)$ or $y \in (pq)$ or there exists no divisor $d$ of $xy$ other than itself such that $d \in (pq)$.

I'm finding it hard to prove this.  Is it true?

---

If $xy \in (pq)$ and $x,y \notin (pq)$, let $d \lt xy$ be a divisor of $xy$ such that $d \in (pq)$.  If $d | x$ then $x \in (pq)$, contrad, sim. if $d| y$.  So let $d = xr_1 \cdots r_k$ for some primes $r_i$.  If $pq$ divides $r_1 \cdots r_k$ then $y \in (pq)$, contrad.  Put $pq z =d = x r_1 \cdots r_k$.  Then either $p$ or $q$ must divide $x$ as $pq$ cannot divide $r_1 \cdots r_k$.

So I guess it's not true as we can choose $p = 3, q = 5$, and $x = p$, $y = q r_2 \cdots r_k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample:

In the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, let 
$$p=2,\;q=3,\;x=10,\;y=15$$
Then $x \notin (pq),\;y \notin (pq)$, but there is a proper divisor of $xy$, for example $pq$, which is in $(pq)$.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that now.  See above edits.  Thank you!